# No filled in data in RadDataGrid

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have an UWP app and I am using a RadDataGrid to show some data. When I do a API call to my API to set data in the grid, the data grid shows empty rows.

My XAML

```
 <tg:RadDataGrid Grid.Row="2" UserGroupMode="Disabled" ColumnDataOperationsMode="Flyout"  x:Name="infoGrid" ItemsSource="{x:Bind  Path=ViewModel.history}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" FontSize="24" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,50" VerticalAlignment="Top" MaxHeight="500">
            <tg:RadDataGrid.Columns>
                <tg:DataGridTextColumn PropertyName="UpdatedBy" Header="Verplaatst door"/>
                <tg:DataGridDateColumn PropertyName="UpdateDate" Header="Bijgewerkt op"  CellContentFormat=" {0:dd/MM/yyyy}" />
                <tg:DataGridTextColumn PropertyName="Location" Header="Verplaatst naar"/>
            </tg:RadDataGrid.Columns>
        </tg:RadDataGrid>
```

My C# code to set data

```cs
 public async void APICALL()
        {
            var result = await LotService.GetLotInfo(ViewModel.scanField);
            ViewModel.lot = result;
            ViewModel.history = result.LotHistory;
            infoGrid.ItemsSource = null;
            infoGrid.ItemsSource = ViewModel.history;
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }
```

ViewModel.history is a List of LotHistoryInfo Class

EDIT: Added getters and setters as mm8 suggested

```
public class LotHistoryInfo
    {
       public LotInfo lot { get; set; }
        public string scanField { get; set; }
        public List<LotHistoryInfo> history { get; set; }

        public LotHistoryInfo(LotStoreHistory his)
        {
             Location = new Location(his.LshStoreid.ToString(), his.LshStorex, his.LshStorey, his.LshStorez);
                UpdatedBy = his.UpdatedBy;
                UpdateDate = his.Updated;

        }
        public LotHistoryInfo()
        {

        }
    }
```

My data grid acknowledges there should be 3 items in it, but it doesnt fill them in. [image: Empty grid]

Sooo, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only bind to public *properties*:

```
public class LotHistoryInfo
{
    public Location Location { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset UpdateDate { get; set; }

    public LotHistoryInfo(LotStoreHistory his)
    {
        Location = new Location(his.LshStoreid.ToString(), his.LshStorex, his.LshStorey, his.LshStorez);
        UpdatedBy = his.UpdatedBy;
        UpdateDate = his.Updated;

    }
    public LotHistoryInfo()
    {

    }
}
```

You have implemented `Location`, `UpdatedBy` and `UpdateDate` as *fields*:

```
public Location Location;
public string UpdatedBy;
public DateTimeOffset UpdateDate;
```

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, I did edit the wrong class, now I did the correct one and it works now